# How to access %APPDATA% in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, electron

I have electron application which contains laravel project, I want to create a sqlite database on booting and store it in AppData Folder. Then from database.php in config folder, I want to access AppData Folder and get the database. Everything works fine in terms of creating the database on booting, but I can't access AppData Folder in laravel. It throws an error.

This is my code for creating database on booting in AppServiceProvider

```
    public function boot()
{           
    
    if(!file_exists('%APPDATA%\pos\database.sqlite')){
         //1. create the file                   
        
        $handle = fopen('%APPDATA%\pos\database.sqlite', 'w') or die('Cannot open file');
        
        Artisan::call('migrate');
        
        fclose($handle);    
    }       
    
    
    
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    Blade::directive('active', function ($url) {
        return "<?php echo request()->is($url.'*') || request()->is($url.'/*')? ' active' : ''; ?>";
    });       

}
```

And here is my sqlite code from database.php

```
        'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'database' => '%APPDATA%\pos\database.sqlite',
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],
```

What should I do ? is there any alternative solutions for retrieving the database in electron ?

Comment: `APPDATA` is an environment variable and will live in `$_ENV` if PHP is configured to populate it. The `%FOO%` format only applies to Window shell environments, not PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`APPDATA` is an environment variable. You can use Laravel's `env()` helper function to access it.

```
$appdata = env('APPDATA');
```

Make sure you have a sensible backup plan for when the `APPDATA` environment variable doesn't exist.